# sed HTML table with a .tsv file

Tags: html, csv, awk, sed, html-table

I have a .tsv file : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9RZ9U8YCSPac2ZJMkpfanNxS0k

and I need to use the sed command to create an HTML table containing the informations of the .tsv files.

I have tried multiple commands like :

```
awk '{print "<tr>\n<td>"$1 $2"</td><td>"$3 $4"</td><td>"$5 $6"</td><td>"$7"</td><td>"$8$9$10"</td><td>"$11"</td>\n</tr>}' employees.tsv
```

But considering the columns don't all have the same number of words it doesn't work.

Each column is separated with a tabulation \t. If you open the file in hexa you'll see all the 09 that are the \t.

So I guess I have to use the tabulations to correctly create the table but I still can't find the command.

I hope some of you can help me on this.

Comment: can you post whatever code that you have tried? Hit Ctrl + M and paste your code into the snippet.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output. Don't expect people to go clicking on external links and if you need an external link because your input is too big to include in your post then your input is too big to expect people to wade through anyway. Use the editor's `{}` button to format the code and sample input/output you post. Read [ask] if you're not sure what's expected in a question.

Comment: I did it, can you see it or it's just me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it with a couple of `sed` commands, indeed.

```
sed -i 's/^/<TR><TD>/' employees.tsv
sed -i 's/$/<\/TD><\/TR>/' employees.tsv
sed -i 's/\t/<\/TD><TD>/g' employees.tsv
echo '<TABLE>' > table.html
cat employees.tsv >> table.html
echo '</TABLE>' >> table.html
```

That's the basic idea. I would go for a script, of course :)
Note the `/g` on the third line for replacing every occurrence in a line, and the usage of regexp operators `^` and `$` to match the start and the end of the line, respectively.

If you want to go full sed, replace the different `cat` and `echo` with:

```
sed -i "1s/^/<TABLE>/" employees.tsv
sed -i "\$a<\/TABLE>" employees.tsv
```

---

Edit: To put this in a script, use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -f
s/^/<TR><TD>/
s/$/<\/TD><\/TR>/
s/\t/<\/TD><TD>/g
1s/^/<TABLE>/
$a<\/TABLE>
```

You can then invoke `./myscript employees.tsv -i` to replace in-place, or `./myscript employees.tsv > employees.html` to let the original file alone.
I am adding this script because I struggled a bit with the last line. Turned out that `\` was to escape `$` from the shell. Pretty obvious in the end.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just wanted to let you know that I tried :      sed -i 's/,/\n/g' employees.tsv 
sed -i 's/"//g' employees.tsv 
sed -i 's/^/<td>/' employees.tsv 
sed -i 's/$/<\/td>/' employees.tsv 
awk ' {print $0; if(NR % 9 == 0 ) print "<tr>"} ' employees.tsv > employees1.tsv 
awk ' {print $0; if(NR % 10 == 0 ) print "</tr>"} ' employees1.tsv > employees2.tsv but it was a little messy so I'll try your solution asap